# Top quarter reps vs bottom quarter reps for squats?

Tags: weightlifting, squats, functional-strength

What do top quarter rep squats train?

I've heard it's explosive power, namely vertical jumping ability. Why is that? Is it actually better than full range of motion squats for that, or simply a more efficient use of training time/energy?

Apart from explosive power, what other benefits may it have?

And how about all the same questions for bottom quarter rep squats? Why might people want to do those?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that people typically initiate their vertical jumps with only a very shallow squat has led a lot of people to assume that the best way to use weighted squats to train the legs for better jumping ability would be to only squat through that same very shallow range of motion.

However this is only a hypothesis, and the research really doesn't support this hypothesis.<sup>[1](https://doi.org/10.1097/01.JSC.0000395628.53820.ae), [2](https://doi.org/10.1519/JSC.0b013e31824ede62)</sup> Quarter squats seem to be no better than and quite possibly inferior to parallel squats for developing jumping ability.

> And how about all the same questions for bottom quarter rep squats? Why might people want to do those?

Maybe the same, ill-conceived idea, but they're trying to get better at twerking rather than jumping? Given that one normally only breathes at the top of a squat, when the load is supported by the skeleton rather than the muscles, bottom quarter squats seem particularly impractical.

Comment: Bottom-quarter squats might be good for learning how to get comfortable with heavy weights at the bottom, sort of like an Anderson squat